# session to exchange data from one page to another

Tags: asp.net

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["namereturn"] != null)
        {
            MVOH.Text = Session["namereturn"].ToString();
        }
  protected void NextPage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e1)
    {

             Session["name"] = Convert.ToInt32(MVOH.Text);
            Response.Redirect("~/Solution.aspx");

    }
```

I am having the above code in first page and trying to pass value from textbox (MVOH) to next page. In the next page I have the code below. It works for the first value but it does not work if i want to change the value in first page and pass it to the next page second time..So I think I have to use count for the nextPage Button but I don't know how to use that and I want to display this value to the text box till i close the browser..Its like the checkout system in Ecommerce where you can go back and change your details..

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["name"] != null)
        {
            TextBox1.Text = Session["name"].ToString();
            Session["namereturn"] = TextBox1.Text;
        }
    }  
protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e1)
    {

        TextBox1.Text = Session["namereturn"].ToString();
        Response.Redirect("~/Details.aspx");
    }
```

Comment: Talking about the code without seeing it is a little hard, please, post some code.

Comment: Shouldn't be angry, I just announced that you didn't post the code. Good questions always receive good answers, especially you got one good. Just think by yourself: ask a question about the code and don't post the code is not the right way, do you agree?

Comment: yes i agree with that thanks anyway..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**What you should techinically do:**

You should be submitting the information from `textbox1` to a postback action related to `page1.cshtml` then redirect to the action that will render `page2.cshtml` and pass the `textbox1` information

**General Example below:**

```
Public ActionResult Page1()
{
    return View();
}
[HttpPost]
Public ActionResult Page1(ViewModel model)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Page2",new{ textbox1 = model.textbox1});
}
Public ActionResult Page2(string textbox1)
{
    var model = new ViewModel;
    model.Textbox2 = textbox1;
    return View(model);
}
```

**Based on your question this is what you want:**

If do not want to carry it back to the server, you could use the `sessionStorage` or `localStorage` from html5  to hold said information from `page1.cshtml` to `page2.cshtml`

**Reference:**
http://www.w3schools.com/Html/html5_webstorage.asp